# Python button alignment

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm facing a problem using TKinter via PyCharm.
The button placing keeps on running.

I've tried grid and pack yet no luck.
Even row , anchor but i keep getting different results.

[image: Keep on failing]

```
jay = Tk()
jay.title("Awesome Software")
jay.geometry("720x560")

searchbutton = Button(jay, text="Setting")
searchbutton.pack(side=TOP)

stopbutton = Button(jay, text="Stop")
stopbutton.pack(side=TOP)

setbutton = Button(jay, text="Search")
setbutton.pack(side=TOP)

mainloop()
```

Comment: We can't help much without seeing your code. And is this diagram what you're *trying* to achieve, or what you're code currently does but you want to change?

Comment: @skrrgwasme, code added already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it ,

```
jay = Tk()
jay.title("Awesome Software")
jay.geometry("720x560")

but_frame = Frame(jay)
searchbutton = Button(but_frame, text="Search")
searchbutton.pack(side=TOP, padx=20,pady=10)

stopbutton = Button(but_frame, text="Stop")
stopbutton.pack(side=TOP,pady=10)

setbutton = Button(but_frame, text="Settings")
setbutton.pack(side=TOP,pady=10)

but_frame.pack(side=LEFT)

mainloop()
```

Build a frame then do it